# GitHub search/code api doesn't works if the repo owner has digits in its name

Tags: search, github-api

While using GitHub search/code api to search for a keyword in a given repo, it gives results of the repo owner has no digits in its name. However if the repo owner has digits then it gives 0 results.
I am attaching screenshot for reference.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfOrb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpM3R.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLg47.png)

While using GitHub search/code api to search for a keyword in a given repo, it gives results of the repo owner has no digits in its name. However if the repo owner has digits then it gives 0 results.